# iPhone--Graphing Large Amounts of Data in one UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to graph large amounts of data in a UIView as a subview of a UIScrollView.  In order to overcome the memory limitations surrounding enormous UIViews, I plan, once the scrollview's offset has reached the maximum or minimum offset, to redraw the view with the new data either with a lesser "x" value if it has reached minimum, or visa versa, and then increase the view's offset to the opposite of its current position (ie MAX-->MIN and MIN-->MAX).  I have attempted this with the following code.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *) scrollViewer {

 CGPoint p = scrollViewer.contentOffset;

 if(p.x==0){
     if(appDel.windownum>0){
         appDel.windownum--;
         [graphview setNeedsDisplay];
     }
 }

 if(p.x==1000){
     if(appDel.pcont>appDel.windownum*100){
         appDel.windownum++;
         [graphview setNeedsDisplay];
     }
 }
}
```

`appDel.windownum` is the reference for the graph section the view is currently displaying. If it equals zero, it is displaying the first hundred values. If it is one, the next hundred, etc.  Once this variable has been reset in the appDelegate, the graph is redrawn with the new index of values, and the scrolloffset is reset.  However, when this code is run, the program crashes. With and error:

> TERMINATING_DUE_TO_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION

It crashes in the simulator. What have I done wrong?

XCode 3.2.1
iPhone Firmware 3.1.3

Comment: Also, how to I get code to display correctly on this forum.  It never seems to work for me.... :/

Comment: About getting the code to display correctly, at least 4 spaces before each code line will do the magic...

Comment: Now regarding the problem: Does it crash also one the simulator? What exception do you get? Have you tried to debug? Does it crash on the first time this code is executed?

Comment: James, your code misformatted because you (1) you used tabs instead of spaces and (2) it was for some reason being treated as a list.

Comment: Have you tried to debug? Can you tell the exact line where it crashes? Does it crash on the first time this code is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem with your code as presented (need more detail) but I do have a design suggestion for the problem of displaying a large graph.

I have become enamored of late with using tables on the iPhone. You can display anything into a table and they can hold any views. It sounds like you are displaying a large, long graph and you could do this in a table and let the table handle the display for you.

You would need to create a custom UITableViewCell that could display a slice of the chart. It would work just like the view you use now except it would display a fixed range in the chart. (You data model would have to be able to chop the data up into rows/ranges.) Then display the cells with no lines.

This way, the tableview handles drawing only those parts of the chart being immediately displayed. That will help with both memory and responsiveness. From the user's perspective, it will look like a single arbitrarily long scrolling graph.

Comment: Okay, a bit of an issue with this solution.  My graph will be view in portrait mode, and will scroll left to right.  UITableViews, it seems, can only scroll up and down, and are not scalable on the x axis.  Given these criteria, could your solution still work?

Comment: No, but why does it have to be in portrait? It's quite normal for iPhone apps to operate in landscape. Landscape would seem to give your users a wider view of the graph. Even if you go with portrait, you will probably want to implement some kind of view swapping solution that mimics a table going sideways. Mobile platforms just don't have the horsepower to handle large graphics. You have to chop them up.

Comment: Sorry to necro this thread, but I think this is a really neat solution, and you can use the table view in portrait mode left/right simply by rotating the table view (and changing it's dimensions of course). tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(PI/2)

Answer (score 0):

It does crash the simulator.  The error produced is: TERMINATING_DUE_TO_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION.

Comment: You should add this additional information to the main body. I'll go ahead and do it for you since I am here. You should always add any addition information in the body of the question. This format is different form a traditional forum.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had not created a bona-fide account, so I couldn't edit the body...I think. 

Anyway, the issue has been resoled.  I had simply forgotten to synthesize windownum in the appDelegate (duuhhh).  Thanks anyway.

Comment: You should check this answer as the correct one so the system knows the question is answered.